# Edit Text values from Recycler View should be updated in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I am able to access the marks but want to store them at their respective locations only (meaning every student gets his marks and not someone else's)

[This is how my Recycler View looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92jgz.png)

[Firebase Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dtjm.png)

I've got to the point where the data is being collected from a single Edit Text but cannot get its way to the right Student node.

Inside onBindViewHolder method

```
myViewHolder.btnUpdateMarks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final View v = view;

                Result r = new Result();
                r.setMarks_scored(myViewHolder.etEnterMarks.getText().toString());

                String text = myViewHolder.etEnterMarks.getText().toString();

                myViewHolder.updateValue(text,r,v);
            }
        });
```

UpdateValue function

```
public void updateValue(String text, Result r, final View v){

            final View view = v;
            final Result result = r;

            FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            final DatabaseReference marksRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Batches").child("BATCH1");

            marksRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot demo : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        marksRef.child("Results").child("-LfB2Jz7vrbv0vMyYA02").setValue(result);
                    }
                }
```

The marksRef is being hardcoded which shouldn't be the way.. I am not finding any possible way of getting those child variables inside the adapter class

Anyone with any better soultion to solving the problem please help! 
Sorry for the bad communication please mention if anything is missing

-----EDIT---------
I have solved the problem by using a string array inside my activity class and passing it to the constructor of my RecyclerViewAdapter.. 
The problem is whenever i am typing anything in the edit text of 2nd or 3rd item after clicking the update button the cursor is automatically going to the first item's edittext
This is my adapter class

```
public class MarksListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MarksListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Result> resultArrayList;
    String[] firebaseChildValues = new String[2];
    String student_uid;


    public MarksListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Result> p, String[] child) {
        context = c;
        resultArrayList = p;
        firebaseChildValues = child;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.marks_list, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        myViewHolder.tvStudentName.setText(resultArrayList.get(i).getName());
        myViewHolder.tvOutOf_List.setText(" / " + resultArrayList.get(i).getTotal_marks());
        myViewHolder.etEnterMarks.setText(resultArrayList.get(i).getMarks_scored());
        myViewHolder.tvStudentUid.setText(resultArrayList.get(i).getStudent_uid());

        myViewHolder.btnUpdateMarks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final View v = view;

                student_uid = myViewHolder.tvStudentUid.getText().toString();
                Result r = new Result();
                r.setMarks_scored(myViewHolder.etEnterMarks.getText().toString());

                String text = myViewHolder.etEnterMarks.getText().toString();

                myViewHolder.updateValue(text, r, v, firebaseChildValues, student_uid);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return resultArrayList.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvStudentName, tvOutOf_List, tvStudentUid;
        EditText etEnterMarks;
        Button btnUpdateMarks;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvStudentName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStudentName);
            etEnterMarks = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.etEnterMarks);
            tvOutOf_List = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvOutOf_List);
            tvStudentUid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStudentUid);
            btnUpdateMarks = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateMarks);
        }

        public void updateValue(String text, Result r, final View v, String[] child, String suid) {

            final View view = v;
            final Result result = r;
            String[] firebaseChildValues = child;
            String resultValue = text;
            String studentUid = suid;

            FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            final DatabaseReference marksRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Batches").child(firebaseChildValues[0]).child(studentUid).child("Results").child(firebaseChildValues[1]);

            marksRef.child("marks_scored").setValue(resultValue).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d("TAG_MARKS", marksRef.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you passing to your recyclerview adapter's constructor? you can pass a list of these child variables. dump your recyclerView Data model

Comment: But still how will i be able to use them inside ViewModler class? @shb

Comment: you can access the list inside the ViewHolder class. Post your adapter class

Comment: I understood what you said and now it's working great but the problem is that whenever i am clicking on second or third item to update them after clicking the update button the cursor automatically goes to the Edit Text present in the first row of Recycler view Can you help ? @shb

Comment: post your adapter class so that I understand your code properly first

Comment: I have updated my question and added the adapter class can you check and help? @shb

Answer (score 0):

Remove `btnUpdateMarks.setOnClickListener` from `onBindViewHolder`

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        myViewHolder.tvStudentName.setText(resultArrayList.get(i).getName());
        myViewHolder.tvOutOf_List.setText(" / " + resultArrayList.get(i).getTotal_marks());
        myViewHolder.etEnterMarks.setText(resultArrayList.get(i).getMarks_scored());
        myViewHolder.tvStudentUid.setText(resultArrayList.get(i).getStudent_uid());
    }
```

In `MyViewHolder` Class set `btnUpdateMarks.setOnClickListener`

```
public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        tvStudentName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStudentName);
        etEnterMarks = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.etEnterMarks);
        tvOutOf_List = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvOutOf_List);
        tvStudentUid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStudentUid);
        btnUpdateMarks = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateMarks);


        btnUpdateMarks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                student_uid = tvStudentUid.getText().toString();
                String text = etEnterMarks.getText().toString();
                Result r = new Result();
                r.setMarks_scored(text);

                int itemClickedPosition = getLayoutPosition();

                //updateValue(text, r, v, firebaseChildValues, student_uid);
                //change your updateValue() method accordingly
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: where should i use the itemClickedPosition variable? Sorry for the late response

Comment: Depends on your use case. if you don't need it, don't use it. I just gave you an extra variable thinking you might ask about the position. if you need to know which item was clicked you can get its position by getLayoutPosition()

Comment: It was the same only I disabled cursor after clicking on submit button @shb

Comment: It should work if you've implemented the way mentioned above, make sure recyclerview is not recreating